# Correct syntax for a constructor in VB?

Tags: constructor, vb6

I was creating a constructor within a class in VB6 but seems the New keyword is a problem that the compiler doesn't allow me to use it I am sure it's a reserved word but why not for a constructor.

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String)
  'Statements
End Sub
```

I get the error pointing to the 'New' keyword. Is there a work around for this or any references for VB6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VB6 class implementation, constructor and destructor are defined through `Class_Initialize` and `Class_Terminate` procedures.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'...
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man now I get the big picture here. So what is your recommendation software for VB application development. I mean what version is user friendly.

Comment: Microsoft strategy is to move to the .Net architecture. VB6 is likely no more supported. So, in my opinion, if you want to continue to code with Visual Basic language, I invite you to use VB.Net with Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: understood, Thank you very much for that piece of information I owe you bigtime man 

Comment: VB6 is roughly 20 years old. There is no reason whatsoever to do new development in VB6. (VBA, which is built into Office etc. is a different story).